# GCC -Bprefix in Cmake

Tags: c++, c, cmake, fortran

I need to use the '-B' prefix when compiling a project. I ran a test with a small hello world program, but I need to incorporate this into the CMakeLists file for a large project now. The project uses C, C++, and Fortran code. I need the same prefix for all languages. How should I specify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the corresponding `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS` variables, like

```
set(PREFIX "your prefix")

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS       "-B${PREFIX}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS     "-B${PREFIX}")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "-B${PREFIX}")
```

Or, if you wish to *append* this flag to existing flags, do

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS       "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}       -B${PREFIX}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS     "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}     -B${PREFIX}")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -B${PREFIX}")
```

See the documentation for [CMAKE_C_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/envvar/CFLAGS.html), [CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/envvar/CXXFLAGS.html), and [CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/envvar/FFLAGS.html).

It seems to me that there should be more direct and CMake-ish ways of doing this, like, probably, setting the `CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH` variable to `${PREFIX}` or something like that, but I am not sure.

Comment: I could not find that "CMAKE_FORTRAN_FLAGS" when I was googling. Thanks for that. Also, it feels to me like that should be something like CMAKE_FLAGS which sets flags for all languages, but I cannot find it.

Comment: @bremen_matt It is actually `CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS`, I'v finally found this in the docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/envvar/FFLAGS.html?highlight=cmake_fortran_flags . I don't think something like `CMAKE_FLAGS` exists: different languages usually need way different flags.